# jQuery : Defining elements in the object literal?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, object-literal

I am trying to define all my main variables within an object called `globals`. The problem is that when it comes to using a previous element such as `membersTab` to grab `faces` I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'membersTab' of undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 var globals = {
  siteWrap      : $('#siteWrap'),
  content       : $('#content'),
  membersTab    : $('#membersTab'),
  faces     : globals.membersTab.find('.member'),
  members       : {},
  mID       : globals.siteWrap.attr('mID'),
  uID       : globals.siteWrap.attr('uID'),
  mTag      : globals.siteWrap.attr('mTag'),
  uFirst        : globals.siteWrap.attr('fn'),
  uLast     : globals.siteWrap.attr('ln'),
  host      : globals.siteWrap.attr('host'),
  dialogueBox   : $('#dialogueBox'),
  screen        : $('#screen').click(function(){ closeDialogue(true); })
  }
```

Comment: Are you initializing this after jQuery is defined?

Comment: Exactly where is this code in relation to other code (incl. libraries)? Is it in it's own `<script>` block?  Inside the jQuery "ready" handler?  Somewhere else?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your definition of `globals` is not inside `$(document).ready()`, it is possible that the page is not yet loaded, hence `$('#membersTab')` returns an empty collection.

Moreover when you declare `faces`, the object `globals` is not yet created.

The simplest way is probably something like

```
globals = {};
globals.membersTab = $('#membersTab');
globals.faces = globals.membersTab.find('.member');
...
```

Comment: But it would still be a jQuery object.

Comment: If the definition of "globals" is inside the "ready" handler, then "globals" is not global. :-)

Comment: "the object `globals` is not yet created" Actually, it is, at least in Firefox. I believe the literal is a shorthand for instantiating the object and adding properties to it one by one.

Comment: I think the object is created only when you end the literal, which is too late. Of course sometimes this does not matter. For instance a member of globals could be a function in which you use globals itself. This is perfectly legitimate, as the function will be invoked later, when globals is finally defined. But in this case you are using globals before you have finished defining it!

Answer (score 0):

The member membersTab isn't initialized until the literal is closed.

First declare the global object. The null assignments are not necessary but are there for clarity and also gives nice code completion if the editor has that support. This could reduce typing errors.

```
var globals = {
    siteWrap = null,
    content = null,
    ...
};
```

Initialize the object once the DOM is loaded.

```
$(function(){
    globals.siteWrap = $('#siteWrap');
    globals.content = $('#content');
    ...
})
```

Comment: ? the variable you create are not even properties of `globals`. And since you do not use `var`, they will end up in global scope. Finally, if you plan to declare all the properties of `globals` later, there is no need to declare them as `null` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for the notes, I updated my answer. I think there might be some reasons to declare the properties when the object is declare.